# How to concat same column values row by axis 0 in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

In my dataframe i want to concat same value of column x rows horizontally ,

**here is my dataframe:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':[-2,-4,-6,-7,-9,-2,-4,-6,-7,-9],'dd':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}）

df_out:
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':[-2,-4,-6,-7,-9],'dd':[1,2,3,4,5],'dd1':['6,7,8,9,10']}）
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter with reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.set_index(['x', df.groupby('x').cumcount()])['dd']
        .unstack()
        .sort_index(ascending=False)
        .add_prefix('dd')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   x  dd0  dd1
0 -2    1    6
1 -4    2    7
2 -6    3    8
3 -7    4    9
4 -9    5   10
```